# How to use vec! macro in a #![no_std] library?

Tags: rust

In standard Rust code, the `vec!` macro is in the prelude and there is no need to make it visible manually. I'm working on a library that doesn't use the standard library and sets `#![no_std]`, so also the prelude isn't visible.

Inside the test code, I *am* using functionality from the standard library, therefore I have a

```
#[cfg(test)]
extern crate std;
```

This works without problems to access functions and datatypes from the standard library, but now I would like to access the `vec!(...)` macro and I don't know how.

`use std::vec::vec!;` results in an error:

```
expected one of `::`, `;`, or `as` here
```

at the position of the exclamation mark.

How can I access this macro instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to [Tims answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51516910/3131852), if you have an embedded system and you have an allocator, but not std, you can use

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate alloc;
```

to be able to use `vec!`

Comment: Do you have any pointer on how I do this exactly? Indeed my platform has `malloc()` and `free()` available. Is there some standard implementation of `GlobalAlloc` or a crate that implements it based on these two functions? Because else rustc complains, that it doesn't find a `#[alloc_error_handler]` function.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it shouldn't be that hard to do it on your own. Just call (via FFI) your malloc and free and implemented the [needed Trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/alloc/trait.GlobalAlloc.html).

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer maybe something like https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fbe68c0a4b50c109ea637a53d136202c&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: @the8472 I'm note sure, if you can use it as an allocator. Yes, you can use the functions on your own, but vec/string/etc need the global allocator.

Answer (score 3):

[`vec!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html) is a macro so you have to add `#[macro_use]`:

```
#[cfg(test)]
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
```

If you are on a nightly compiler, you can also use the *use_extern_macros* feature:

```
#![feature(use_extern_macros)]

#[cfg(test)]
extern crate std;

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use std::vec;
}
```

Comment: The question is about **`#![no_std]`**, hence `extern crate std;` **obviously** won't work.

Comment: @Michael the Question is about using `vec!` in tests for a `#![no_std]` crate. The testing framework depends on `std`, otherwise it cannot compile.

Comment: My mistake. The question made it seem like the test couldn't use `std`.